# Asynchronous concating strings in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What is the best solution to concate lots of strings?
I wanna get a lot of information from my mongodb database and send via email. I have a lot of data to concate. The usual way is:

```
var str1 = "Hello ";
var str2 = "world!";
var res = str1.concat(str2);
```

I have some array:

```
var strs = {'str0','str1','str2',.....};
```

I need something like this:

```
asyncConcate(strs,function (result)
{
console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code and see if it helps:

(used node.js async module https://github.com/caolan/async)

```
var async = require("async");
var finalResult = "";
var strArray = ["str1","str2","str3"];
var limit = strArray.length-1;

async.forEachLimit(strArray,limit,function(item,callback){
    finalResult+=item;
    callback(); 
});
console.log(finalResult);
```